# MySQL AND OR Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to get a query to work and would like a bit of guidance

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE username =  'bob'
AND device_1 =  'test'
OR device_2 =  'test'
OR device_3 =  'test'
```

It seems to be displaying any row with the word test in it no matter if I'm specifying the username or not.

I'm quite lost with this, its most probably something simple and I'm looking straight past it.

Comment: Whoever voted me down on my first post thanks ... Really inspiring - At least be man enough to come out and say why exactly - WOULD LIKE A BIT OF GUIDANCE , Jesus get a heart

Comment: Your question could probably stand to be less vague. This community is composed of experienced programmers, and when someone downvotes a post, they usually have a good reason; talking back will just discourage future answerers.

Comment: What else can I add ? I'm new - I asked for guidance, I displayed what I've tried and what is happening. I don't really care if it discourages future answers to be honest. If someone has such a good reason then why don't they care to share.

Comment: Generally, it's implied that you've read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and have seen a few other questions, and therefore know what degree of clarity is expected. Discouraging future answerers is important, as you'll eventually end up not getting *any* answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some parentheses to the `WHERE` clause otherwise the `username` filter is only applied to `device_1 =  'test'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE username =  'bob'
AND
( 
  device_1 =  'test'
  OR device_2 =  'test'
  OR device_3 =  'test'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users
WHERE  username = 'bob' AND 
       'test' IN (device_1, device_2, device_3)
```

the `IN` performs the same with multiple `OR`